# Flutter Wifi Connection to listed Wifi

Tags: flutter, dart, connection, wifi

I am new to Flutter. I am developing an application. What I want in this application is to list wifi networks and provide wifi connection within the application by entering the password information of the wifi I choose. I have tried many different flutter packages, they can perform operations such as listing wifi networks, printing wifi network information. What I want is to connect to the wifi network within the application.

I have tried these packages:

- wifi_scan: ^0.4.1
- plugin_wifi_connect: ^1.0.2
- network_info_plus: ^4.1.0+1
- wifi_iot: ^0.3.19

I didn't receive any errors but I also couldn't connect to any networks.
I have tried wifi_iot: ^0.3.19 package but it doesn't allow me for some features that are must for me. I also couldn't connect wifi with this package.I would be grateful if you can help me. Thanks for your support in advance.

Comment: You can check this package: https://pub.dev/packages/wifi_connector/example

You just need to pass ssid and password to connect to wifi

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried but couldn't get it to work